# Prove that all linegraphs L(G) are claw free

Tags: graph-theory

**For any graph G, prove that the line graph L(G) is claw-free.**

I have a fairly good intuition for this one but it's hard to put into words. I really need help with this one! I feel that I should use the pigeonhole principle...

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:** What would a claw in $L(G)$ (as an induced subgraph) correspond to in the original graph $G$?